# Why is this WPF Button background not changing behind an image?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

My squares are either `SaddleBrown` or `WhiteSmoke` in color, shifting to `DarkTurquoise` when selected. This works when there is no image on top of the squares. When I have a (PNG) image on top of the square the original `SaddleBrown`/`WhiteSmoke` color shows behind it but when the color is supposed to change to `DarkTurquoise` nothing happens to the background color of the square.

What could be the problem?

```
<ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
        <Button x:Name="Square"
                Command="{Binding DataContext.BoardGUI.SquareClickCommand, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=ItemsControl}}"
                CommandParameter="{Binding}">
            <Button.Template>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
                    <Grid Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
                        <Image Source="{Binding Source, Converter={StaticResource NullImageConverter}}"/>
                    </Grid>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Button.Template>
        </Button>

        <DataTemplate.Triggers>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding SquareColor}" Value="Dark">
                <Setter TargetName="Square" Property="Background" Value="SaddleBrown"/>
            </DataTrigger>

            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding SquareColor}" Value="White">
                <Setter TargetName="Square" Property="Background" Value="WhiteSmoke"/>
            </DataTrigger>

            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsSelected}" Value="True">
                <Setter TargetName="Square" Property="Background" Value="DarkTurquoise"/>
            </DataTrigger>
        </DataTemplate.Triggers>
    </DataTemplate>
</ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
```

Comment: Are you 100% sure that IsSelected is set to true(including raising propertychanged)? Please check with debugger. Probably it isnt set to true due to the png

Comment: Yes. When I manually set IsSelected to true for all Dark pieces (i.e the `SaddleBrown` ones) they turn into `DarkTurquoise` except the ones that have images on top. See image [here](http://i.imgur.com/5lgqyBU.png).

Comment: Is it possible that "SquareColor" is being set or changed after IsSelected is set to true for those squares?

Comment: Thank you, that was it. SquareColor was set in the constructor and IsSelected was set in brackets after creating the new Square and it seems the constructor was executed after the brackets.

Comment: Glad that was it.  I'm going to post as an answer based on what I read here http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251597/question-with-no-answers-but-issue-solved-in-the-comments

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As determined in the comments, based on the screenshot and the definition of the triggers, it appears that "SquareColor" is likely getting set or changed after IsSelected is set.